# AlarmManager + Some sort of UI interface

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, countdowntimer

I need to make my app so that I have a timer running on the screen, and if it reaches 0, some code is executed, but the timer can be reset by the user.

Now I understand the AlarmManager [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html] is the platform to use when one needs code to be executed at a certain time, but how do I get the GUI display of the contents of the AlarmManager? For example, how do I show the timer that, when it finishes, executes the AlarmManager's code?

I'm currently using CountDownTimer, but that only runs when the app is open, and I need it to run at all times as well as execute code if/when it finishes.

If anyone has tutorials or any experience with this, please help!

Comment: You know the moment when you set your AlarmManager, use System.currentTimeMillis() and you know moment when youar alarm is going to trigger, you can always display difference of those times, even when you close your app and start it again

Comment: It'd be a lot easier if I could run CountDownTimer and then under onFinish() trigger my code. Is this possible? That way I can have an easy user interface too